# Javascript: combine 2 objects into one

Tags: javascript, pointers, object, data-structures, reference

Is it possible to define a variable C to be a combination of 2 objects(let's say A and B), so that anything happens to A and B  **at any time in the future** will happen to C. This means, **C is declared before any change to A and B**. For example:

```
var A = {};
var B = {};
var C = combine(A, B);

A.a=1;
B.b=2;

console.log(C);
// { a:1, b:2 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: Um.. with your updated question *and in the future* -- that just ain't gunna happen.  If you limit yourself to a handful of restricted property names, you could play games with creating an subscriber/publisher pattern and then use the ES5 getters/setters to push changes out -- but dang.  No.

Comment: Not a dup--this is asking for dynamic updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C would have to be a function:

```
function extend(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object') return obj;
    Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1).forEach(function (source) {
        for (var prop in source) {
            obj[prop] = source[prop];
        }
    });
    return obj;
};

var A = {};
var B = {};
var C = function () {
    var _c = {};
    return extend(_c, A, B);
};
```

Then call C like:

```
A.a=1;
B.b=2;

console.log(C());
// { a:1, b:2 }
```